# How do I watch for changes in PHP files using gruntjs?

Tags: php, gruntjs, yeoman

I started a `yeoman` project with the *webapp-generator* and now I would like to add some PHP my project.

What should I do so they are:

1. copied during `grunt build` ;
2. watched/updated into the `dist/` directory if modification occurs during `grunt server` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work with the following modification:

Inside the *grunt.initConfig({…})*, I add an entry to the `watch`'s task configuration item:

```
    copyPhp: {
        files: [
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.php'
        ],
        tasks: ['copy:php']
     }
```

Then I updated the `copy`'s task configuration –to add a `php` entry– so it matches the task `copy:php` defined in `copyPhp`:

```
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,txt}',
                    '*.{php,phpc}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    'images/assets/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                    'images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}',
                    'styles/fonts/*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        php: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{php,phpc}',
                ]
            }]
        }
    },
```

You can also see that, in the `dist`, I added a line to copy PHP files to the dist directory:

```
     '*.{php,phpc}',
```

## Extra

I also added a line in the `livereload` configuration. Howerver, as I'm using Apache instead of the internal server with [grunt-php](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-php), this is pointless and need more work.

```
'<%= yeoman.app %>/*.php',
```